# python: unicode function vs u prefix

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, string-formatting

I ran into trouble with a `UnicodeEncodeError` in my Django project and ended up solving the issue (after much frustration) by changing the return value of the at-fault `__unicode__` method from

```
return unicode("<span><b>{0}</b>{1}<span>".format(val_str, self.text))
```

to

```
return u"<span><b>{0}</b>{1}<span>".format(val_str, self.text)
```

But I'm confused why this worked (or rather, why there was an issue in the first place). Do the `u` prefix and the `unicode` function not do the same thing? When trying it in a console, they seem to give the same result:

```
# with the function
test = unicode("<span><b>{0}</b>{1}<span>".format(2,4))
>>> test
u'<span><b>2</b>4<span>'
>>> type(test)
<type 'unicode'>

# with the prefix
test = u"<span><b>{0}</b>{1}<span>".format(2,4)
>>> test
u'<span><b>2</b>4<span>'
>>> type(test)
<type 'unicode'>
```

But it seems the encoding is somehow done differently depending on what's used. What's going on here?

Comment: What Python version is this?

Comment: 2.7.

Sorry, that makes a difference with the way Python 3 now handles strings/unicode.

Comment: In the unicode function version, you format, then "unicodize". Is the problem with the formatting?

Comment: Ah, yes, `unicode("<span><b>{0}</b>{1}<span>").format(val_str, self.text)` works. But why does the formatting part break it? Both the values it's getting are unicode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem lies with what you applied `unicode()` *to*; your two expressions are **not** equivalent.

```
unicode("<span><b>{0}</b>{1}<span>".format(val_str, self.text))
```

applies `unicode()` to the result of:

```
"<span><b>{0}</b>{1}<span>".format(val_str, self.text)
```

while

```
u"<span><b>{0}</b>{1}<span>".format(val_str, self.text)
```

is the equivalent of:

```
unicode("<span><b>{0}</b>{1}<span>").format(val_str, self.text)
```

Note the placement of the closing parenthesis!

So, your first version *formats first*, and only *then* converts the result of the formatting to unicode. This is an important difference!

When using `str.format()` with `unicode` values, those values are passed to `str()`, which implicitly *encodes* those strings to ASCII. This causes your exception:

```
>>> 'str format: {}'.format(u'unicode ascii-range value works')
'str format: unicode ascii-range value works'
>>> 'str format: {}'.format(u"unicode latin-range value doesn't work: å")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe5' in position 40: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It doesn't matter that you call `unicode()` on the result; the exception has already been raised.

Formatting with `unicode.format()` on the other hand has no such problems:

```
>>> u'str format: {}'.format(u'unicode lating-range value works: å')
u'str format: unicode lating-range value works: \xe5'
```

Comment: Ah, that's the trick! Calling `format` on the str instead of unicode tries to convert the arguments to ascii, which doesn't work.